# Tag links not working with acts as taggable on and Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm currently using the following gems in my application to provide pagination, search, linkable tags, and a tag cloud.

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~>2.1.0'

I have everything implemented so far in Rails 3.1 except the tag links. I have them displayed below every post and in the tag cloud and both link to different views and neither works.

A link in the tag cloud (Test1) links me to: /posts/tag?id=Test1 which gives me an error "Couldn't find Post with id=tag"

And a link in the post redirects me to /posts?tag=Test2&view=tag which doesn't change anything. All my posts are still displayed.

Here's what I've changed so far to try and implement this:

The edited part of my routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
collection do
  get :tag
end
```

end

My post.rb:

```
acts_as_taggable_on :tags
def self.tag_post_list(page, tag)

  Post.tagged_with(tag).by_date.paginate(:page => params[page], :per_page => 20)

end
```

Post_Controller.rb:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search], params[:page])
  @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  if request.xhr?
    render :partial => @posts
  end
end
def tag
  @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:id])
  @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  render :action => 'index'
end
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end
```

Posts_helper.rb:

```
include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
```

Tag cloud in application.html.erb

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
<%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Tag cloud definition in application_controller.rb

```
def tag_cloud
  @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
end
```

Links in my posts:

```
<% for tag in post.tags %>
<%= link_to tag.name, posts_path(:view =>'tag', :tag => tag.name) %>
<% end %>
```

The error in my console:

```
Started GET "/posts/tag?id=Test1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-05 00:35:00 -0700
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"tag"}
Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "tag"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with id=tag): app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:33:in `show'
```

I've searched the internet for the past 5 hours trying to figure this out, but nothing is up to date or entirely relevant.

I get that it is passing "tag" to the show action, but how do I get it to pass the relevant ID and anything else I need to show the correct posts with that tag?

Comment: This is a routing problem. Run 'rake routes' and copy/paste the relevant section to your question please (all the lines that include `:controller=>"posts"`)

Comment: Thanks, here it is: http://pastebin.com/sDQRrUwk Also I tried this: match "/post/:tag" => "posts#show", :as => :tag and it still wont match the tag action in my post controller.

Comment: Also I'm thinking that I need to add :via => :get to the route, but when I did, it still didn't work. I'm making some simple mistake I know, but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake:

I wasn't passing paginate to the @posts array in the tag definition.

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Work's perfectly. Thanks for the help, you were part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `rake routes` output, here's your problem:

```
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
    ...
tag_posts GET    /posts/tag(.:format)         {:action=>"tag", :controller=>"posts"}
```

the URL `/posts/tag?id=Test1` is matched by both these routes, so the first one is used, leading to the `posts#show` action being called instead of the `posts#tag` action as intended.

Now I'm not quite sure why that is - you seem to have too many routes defined for the posts controller. Do you have any other entries for `posts` somewhere in your routes file in addition to the one you have in your question?

With just this:

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get :tag
  end
end
```

your `rake route` output should look like this:

```
tag_posts GET    /posts/tag(.:format)       {:action=>"tag", :controller=>"posts"}
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
          POST   /posts(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

Here the `tag_post` route is defined prior to the default `post` route, which would fix your issue.

**EDIT**:

Based on your comment, change the route you added slightly to this:

```
match "/posts/tag/:id" => "posts#tag", :as => :tag_posts
```

and then use the named route in your link:

```
link_to tag.name, tag_posts_path(tag.name)
```

Comment: Alright routing errors are fixed. I changed the route.rb to: 'match "/posts/tag" => "posts#tag", :as => :tag_posts
  resources :posts, :sessions' But now the links do not search for the posts with the associated tags. Is there something wrong in the tag definition in my posts controller?

Comment: It's probably the action in this <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %> How do I get it to return the results from the tag definition?

Comment: Ok, no routing errors, but the links still don't work. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the "@post = Post.find(params[:id])" in the tag definition and the "@posts = Post.search(params[:search], params[:page])" in the index definition. The index overrides the value of @post that was changed in the tag definition. Can I write an if statement that checks to see if the parameter passed was a search query or a tag? If so, how? I'm fairly new to Ruby and Rails and MVC in general, just trying to learn how everything is structured.